# How do I change the format of a decimal number in EpPlus?

Tags: c#, excel, numbers, decimal, epplus

My office Excel is confirate in French Format (separator decimal = Point and separator thousand = space )
i load a sheet with csv file with french format decimal number :

My code:

```
var range = sheet.Cells["A3"].LoadFromText(new FileInfo(fileCSVFull), format, TableStyles.Medium27, true);
var numStyle = package.Workbook.Styles.CreateNamedStyle("TableNumber");
numStyle.Style.Numberformat.Format = "# ##0,00";

var tbl = sheet.Tables[0];
tbl.ShowTotal = true;
tbl.Columns[0].TotalsRowLabel = "Total";

tbl.Columns[1].TotalsRowFunction = RowFunctions.Sum;
tbl.Columns[1].DataCellStyleName = "TableNumber";
tbl.Columns[2].TotalsRowFunction = RowFunctions.Sum;
tbl.Columns[2].DataCellStyleName = "TableNumber";
tbl.Columns[3].TotalsRowFunction = RowFunctions.Sum;
tbl.Columns[3].DataCellStyleName = "TableNumber";

string numcell = "E4:E"+(3 + nbline); 
sheet.Cells[numcell].Formula = "B4*C4";
sheet.Cells[numcell].StyleName = "TableNumber";

sheet.View.ShowGridLines = false;
sheet.Calculate();
sheet.Cells[sheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
```

But i have an exception on "sheet.Calculate();" 
What if I change the format of my decimal number that's good my XLSX file is generated but I have an error when I open Excel as my decimal format is not recognized by my French version of Excel.

Comment: Open Excel and format a cell the way you want it, then right click the cell and choose the "Format Cells" option and select the "Custom" option. You'll see what Excel is expecting the number format to be to get your desired output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I generates 50 files per day and I can not ask my customer to do this action every time!
How to EPPLUS that takes into account the regional setting ?

Comment: I'm saying that *you* can do this to determine what the French version of Excel itself sets for the number format text for the format you want and then put that number format in your code.

Comment: That's what I tried to do. I loaded a CSV file with comma as decimal separator (eg 12 235,55 ) and I indicated Numberformat.Format = " # ## 0,00 " but when the statement ( sheet.Calculate (); ) is executed , an exception is thrown

Answer (score 4):

I faced the similar issue. Setting format string to `"#,##0.00"` did the trick in my case.

Comment: I expect that EPPlus, unlike Excel, always uses the en-US locale when interpreting custom number format strings. That means that the format string should use `,` (comma) for thousand separator and `.` (dot) for decimal separator.